# Vertical lines in editor bar are misaligned

Tags: bug, status-deferred, google-chrome, anonymous-user, safari

While logged out on Mobile Safari, when I go to a question page on Stack Overflow and scroll down to the editor, I see this…

[image]

The vertical lines in the menu bar aren't aligned correctly.

Comment: I can’t reproduce this with either dark or light theme. Using built in Safari on iOS 16.1.1.

Comment: No repro here as well (on Google Chrome on mobile)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi What if you log out?

Comment: No repro for me either (mobile safari, logged out, iOS 16.0.2, iPhone 14 pro max), so there’s something else at play here. I assume you’re able to reproduce this on multiple questions @JasonPunyon?

Comment: @JohnM.Wright Yeah, multiple questions, multiple sites, as long as i'm logged out. iOS 16.0.3, iPhone 14 Pro.

Comment: I can reproduce it on Android, both in [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oyjs.png) and [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW8wi.png), but only when I'm logged out.

Comment: I can definitely repro this on Chrome for Android and Chrome for Windows (after changing the viewport to some mobile dimensions). Also, only when I'm logged out. Edit: the problem goes away as soon as the answer box is activated.

Comment: You can see it in action here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQyAK.gif

Comment: @DonaldDuck [meta-tag:mobile-web] is for questions about the now retired mobile-web app. Currently, SO is responsive, meaning that the same app is served to desktop and mobile browsers.

Comment: ok, I'm able to repro it using Chrome on Windows and setting the width of the viewport to 420 or less.  Note that above 420px, there are NO vertical bars in the editor toolbar, so it's a matter of them showing at all at small widths, not just that they are misplaced.

Comment: I had to remove a tag in order to add the status* tag, so dropped the [firefox] tag since it's the lesser used of the three tagged browsers.

Comment: I've marked this as [status-deferred] since it's a valid request but the Stacks team has limited capacity at the moment, so it's on their backlog for now.